# Error: Don't know how to add e2 to a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Hello I am working on a data set which looks like as below

```
raw_data = 

week    v1         v3         v4            v5          v6
1      17         20.983819   7.799831    16.0600278  113.018687
2      34         22.651678   8.090671    16.4898951  120.824817
3      15         24.197048   6.892516    16.9805836  128.105372
4      14         26.016688   5.272781    17.471264   140.15794
5      26         27.572317   10.767018   17.8686156  154.886518
6      37         29.018684   21.280104   19.8096452  165.244061
7      27         30.395094   32.140543   22.937902   176.453934
8      24         31.832068   44.008145   28.714597   184.7598
9      16         33.383742   45.704626   39.2958153  193.461108
10     28         34.877819   39.355206   45.9069661  201.305558
```

What I am trying to achieve is to plot variables from v3 to v6 as a stacked area plot while variable v1 as a line plot in the same graph plot across the week.

I have tried the following code which does plot the stack area plot but not the line plot.

```
mdf <- melt(raw_data, id="Week")  # convert to long format
p <- ggplot(mdf, aes(x=Week, y=value)) + geom_area(aes(fill= mdf$variable), position = 'stack') + theme_classic()
p + ggplot(raw_data, aes(x=Week, y=v1)) +geom_line()
```

and I get the following error

```
Error: Don't know how to add e2 to a plot
```

I tired the method suggested by this article [How to overlay geom_bar and geom_line plots with different number of elements using ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147739/how-to-overlay-geom-bar-and-geom-line-plots-with-different-number-of-elements-us) and used the below code

```
mdf <- melt(raw_data, id="Week")  # convert to long format
p <- ggplot(mdf, aes(x=Week, y=value)) + geom_area(aes(colour = 
mdf$variable, fill= mdf$variable), position = 'stack') + theme_classic()
p + geom_line(aes(x=Week, y=mdf$variable=="v1"))
```

but then I got the below error

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

I tried to convert the v1 variable as per below code referencing the following article, however it did not help to resolve.

[How do I get discrete factor levels to be treated as continuous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386314/how-do-i-get-discrete-factor-levels-to-be-treated-as-continuous)

```
raw_data$v1 <- as.numeric(as.character(raw_data$v1))
```

Please help how to resolve the issue. Also, how do I create a black border line for each graph in my stacked graph such that it is easy to differentiate among the graphs.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance!!

Comment: Your `melt` command does not work for me.

Comment: Try replacing your third line with `p + geom_line(data=raw_data, aes(x=Week, y=v1))` - you should not add another `ggplot` to `p`

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you mean by melt does not work. I just used it to convert the data frame to long format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your `melt` command does not work for me, so I'm using `gather` instead.

All you need to do is add `geom_line` and specify the data and mapping:

```
mdf <- tidyr::gather(raw_data, variable, value, -week, -v1)

ggplot(mdf, aes(week, value)) + 
  geom_area(aes(fill = variable), position = 'stack', color = 'black') + 
  geom_line(aes(y = v1), raw_data, lty = 2)
```

Note: don't use `$` inside `aes`, ever!

Comment: thanks a lot @Axeman. This is exactly what I was looking for. I am new to gglpot and trying to learn on the go. Point taken, would not use $ in aes ever again.